# Possibility of having "dynamically-binded" and "implicit" interface?

Tags: oop, programming-languages

Is there any construct that allows all classes which implemented a set of functions to be considered as a certain interface, even when the classes themselves do not explicitly implement the interface?

To make the question clearer, I'll make an example. Suppose we want to implement `LinearSearch`, which look through the whole array and search for certain key, and return the index of the key upon discovery. Essentially, the psudeocode might look something like this:

```
LinearSearch(A, key)
    for (k = 0; k < A.length(); k++)
        if (A.get(k) == key)
            return k
    return NULL
```

In that case, any classes which implemented `length` and `get` will be able to search through the structure. We could implement this on `DynamicArray`, which acts the same as `ArrayList` in Java. We could implement this on a `LinkedList`, ignoring the fact the `get` takes linear time per query. Similarly for other structures that implement these 2 functions. However, such classes might not have explicitly implemented a common interface, even though it is favorable to have them being in one.

While writing this question, I feel a sense of insecurity tinkering within me about such a construct, but I cannot put it into words. So, is there any reason you think that this might not be a good construct in actual languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "duck typing". Message-based object models like Smalltalk allow sending *any* message to an object as long as its name and parameters match.

In languages like C++, you can emulate this using "signals" and "slots", which, at their most primitive, can be implemented by writing a little template adapter class like

```
class CallGetLengthAdapterBase
{
public:
    int length() = 0;
    key_type key() = 0;
};

template<class N>
class CallGetLengthAdapter : public CallGetLengthAdapterBase
{
public:
    CallGetLengthAdapter( N* obj ) { mObject = obj; };

    int length() { return mObject->length(); };
    key_type key() { return mObject->key(); };
protected:
    N*          mObject;
};
```

So the LinearSearch would just know about `CallGetLengthAdapterBase`, and would take a pointer to an object of this type. Whoever owns and connects both of these objects would call them like:

```
LinearSearch( CallGetLengthAdapter<A_type>(&A), key );
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)):

> Go has "interface" types that are compatible with any type that supports a given set of methods (the type does not need to explicitly implement the interface). The empty interface, `interface{}`, is compatible with all types.

It sounds like this is what you mean, so it is another sense of interface than we might be used to from Java or such. This is a [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) kind of interface, where the structure of methods involved are the important part, not a name given to the interface.

More formally, it seems that this is called a [type class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class).